# Serializing the errors hash in ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm using ActiveModel::Serializer to customize the JSON responses for my API.  This works fine in most cases, except when it fails to save a model successfully.

For example,

```
def create
  def create
    book = Book.new(book_params)
    book.save

    respond_with book, location: nil
  end
end
```

As I understand it, the respond_with action will basically execute code that looks something like this (in order to generate the response).

```
  if resource.errors.any?
    render json: {:status => 'failed', :errors => resource.errors}
  else
    render json: {:status => 'created', :object => resource}
  end
```

This does match up with what I'm seeing - if my model fails to save successfully I see the errors hash as the response.  However, I can't figure out how I specify a serializer for the errors hash.

I tried defining an ErrorsSerializer and if I run

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(book.errors)
```

in the console it seems to find my serializer, but it doesn't get used.  How do I customize the JSON response in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the problem in this case is that for the `failed` status you won't call `render` with an object, like for `created` status.

You can use a custom Serializer when calling `render`, for this case you can probably use something like

```
if resource.errors.any?
  render serializer: ErrorSerializer, json: {:status => 'failed', :errors => resource.errors}
else
  render json: {:status => 'created', :object => resource}
end
```

Give it a try and keep us informed of the result :)

Answer (score 8):

I found this answer on [this blog post](http://jaketrent.com/post/jsonapi-errors-serializer-in-rails/) ... which starts as such ...

> The default serialization of error states in Rails might not be what
>   you want for your app. In that case, it’d be worth knowing how to
>   write a custom serialization format for your needs. In my case, I am
>   trying to match the [JSON API format for errors](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors). Here’s a potential
>   implementation…

**Example validation error**

By default, Rails 4 will return an error serialization that looks like this (for a book model where `title` should always be present):

```
{
  "title": [
    "can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

**Create a custom error serializer**

In `/serializers/error_serializer.rb` ...

```
module ErrorSerializer

  def self.serialize(errors)
    return if errors.nil?

    json = {}
    new_hash = errors.to_hash(true).map do |k, v|
      v.map do |msg|
        { id: k, title: msg }
      end
    end.flatten
    json[:errors] = new_hash
    json
  end
end
```

**Use it in your controller**

Now `include ErrorSerializer` in your controller so that you can do something like this using the errors hash i.e. `render: json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(book.errors)`

**Result**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "id": "title",
      "title": "Title can't be blank"
    }
  ]
}
```

Read the actual post for the *deets*.

Answer (score 4):

The `ErrorsSerializer` doesn't work because of how responders create json response for errors:

```
def json_resource_errors
  { errors: resource.errors }
end
```

(rails < 4.2 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb#L290 for newer rails, responders have been extracted to https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/blob/master/lib/action_controller/responder.rb#L288)

one way of dealing with this is to override this method for responders. Put this code in your config initializers:

```
# config/initializers/action_controller_responder.rb
module ActionController
  class Responder
    def json_resource_errors
      resource.errors
    end
  end
end
```

Then your serializer will work for resource errors.

Answer (score 2):

The class name of resource.errors is `ActiveModel::Errors` so you have to define you class as 
`ActiveModel::ErrorsSerializer`.

Ref: [source code](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0c13956311eddf8e57cde3d4223aa612bf80ab9e/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L64)

Comment: Yup, that's what I did.  As I said in my question - it finds my serializer when I do ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for, but it doesn't get used.

Comment: can you update the question with the your ErrorSerializer code?